# Button in pricing-table Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, button

Tenho um código que mostra pricing-table na minha View. Cada um tem um botão em javascript que quando clica nele precisa abrir uma outra View aonde tem os detalhes de cada pricing-table. Como posso fazer para que cada botão ao clicar apareça escritas diferentes. 
Ex: se clicar no primeiro botão, ele abre uma view com um titulo apenas, e quando eu clicar no botão 2 abre uma view com um titulo e texto.
Meu código usa bootstrap e está em Codeigniter

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="well well-light">
                <h1>Planos, <small>4 Planos</small></h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-teal pricing-big">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Personal Project
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body no-padding text-align-center">
                                <div class="the-price">
                                    <h1>
                                        $99<span class="subscript">/ mo</span>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-features">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-left">
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> 2 years access <strong> to all storage locations</strong></li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> <strong>Unlimited</strong> storage</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> Superbig <strong> download quota</strong></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer text-align-center">
                                <button id="plano_1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                    Contratar <span>plano</span>
                                </button>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i>We accept all major credit cards</i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary pricing-big">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Developer Bundle
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body no-padding text-align-center">
                                <div class="the-price">
                                    <h1>
                                        $350<span class="subscript">/ mo</span>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-features">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-left">
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> 2 years access <strong> to all storage locations</strong></li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> <strong>Unlimited</strong> storage</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> Superbig <strong> download quota</strong></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer text-align-center">
                                <button id="plano_2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Contratar <span>plano</span></button>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i>We accept all major credit cards</i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#plano_1").on('click', function () {
        window.location = ('<?= base_url('index#ConPla/verPla1') ?>/');
    });
    $("#plano_2").on('click', function () {
        window.location = ('<?= base_url('index#ConPla/verPla1') ?>/');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Por acaso vai abrir uma nova página? Se sim, pq não faz um link normal?

Comment: @MarceloDiniz ele vai carregar na página mesmo só irá mudar a View.

Comment: por acaso esse ConPla eh um controller? Tenta tirar o index#

Comment: @MarceloDiniz eu tinha colocado sem o index, porém ao clicar no botão fazia com carregasse apenas a página, tirando o menu e outras opções que precisam continuar ali. Com o index ele mudará apenas o "meio da página, mantendo o padrão dela.

Comment: consegue colocar um exemplo no jsfiddle ou algo parecido?